# In Better Call Saul, Jimmy first has some idea of the existence of Gus Fring -- how does he get to actually know of him?

Tags: breaking-bad, better-call-saul

In Season 6, Episode 8 of *Better Call Saul*, Lalo sends (it turns out) Kim to shoot Fring -- at this point, Jimmy has no idea who Fring is, I believe. The killing of course does not occur. But it is Saul who provides Walt entrée to Fring in *Breaking Bad*. Is it possible that despite Jimmy's role in his potential killing, it is I guess through Mike that Saul now has information that allows him to tell Walt how to meet Fring? I would think after Mike's cleaning up the murder scene, Jimmy would have no further contact with Mike.

Comment: Most of your post is hidden under spoiler markup/protection. Could you consider editing your post to provide more context outside of the spoiler-hidden text? I suggest using spoiler markup sparingly, and only for the most spoilery parts of your post. Relevant meta posts regarding spoiler protection: [\[1\]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114923/162827) [\[2\]](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16/1006) [\[3\]](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/82/1006).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witness_(Better_Call_Saul) + https://screenrant.com/better-call-saul-jimmy-gus-salamanca-breaking-bad-setup/ etc.

Comment: Just watch later episodes.

Comment: "At this points, Jimmy has no idea..." I was under the impression that until season 4 of Breaking Bad, Jimmy/Saul had only hints of who Fring was, and certainly never met him beyond the encounter where Jimmy dug through the LPH trashcan.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins, that's why in BrBa Saul says "I know a guy that knows a guy… that knows a guy". He's aware that Gus exists(not by name, ofc, but as local drugdealing kingpin, rival to Salamancas), and knows that Mike has connections to Gus. And that's it.

Answer (score 5):

Saul tells Walt: ["I know a guy who knows a guy ... who knows another guy"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KqTVkUxMUi8&ab_channel=DaveLowe). He talks to Mike about Walt, and then Mike talks to Gus. All Walt is then told is to go to a particular Pollo Hermanos location and wait. Walt doesn't know who he's meeting, and Saul likely doesn't as well. Although even if he did know Gus, he probably wouldn't admit it at this point, as he wanted to maintain plausible deniability if things went bad.

Answer (score 3):

Jimmy/Saul never meets Gus Fring in Better Call Saul.*

In Better Call Saul, he interacts only with Mike Ehrmantraut. Of course Jimmy/Saul is aware that Mike is working for someone behind the scenes, but he never actually meets Gus.

In S06E08, Lalo tells Jimmy and Kim to go to a house and kill someone who's "Black, medium height, short hair, glasses. He kind of looks like a librarian."

Jimmy doesn't go to the house and instead Kim goes. When she goes there, she incorrectly identifies one of the black bodyguards as the intended target.

---

*Other than a very brief interaction in S03 when Jimmy is digging in a trash can at Pollos Hermanos and Gus (who's sweeping the floor) offers to help him look for whatever he's looking for. (Here Gus probably knows something's up, but to Jimmy, Gus is just another employee that he won't remember.)

Comment: "one of the black bodyguards as the intended target" — more like a body double, who's job IS to look exactly like Gus Fring.

Comment: @user28434 One wonders if looking like Fring is his sole function or if indeed he also is armed and a bodyguard -- why not? I wonder about drone bees which I believe do actually occasionally do work in the hive (I think they help cool it).

Comment: @releseabe, well, nothing prevents this body double from defending himself. Gus Fring would do that too, if he was attacked. But the primary role was still to make attackers believe he's the real Gus, and their main target.